# How do I change the DNS adresses on a BT Homehub 3?

Tags: router, dns, wireless-router, opendns

I am trying to set up OpenDNS on my home router and I can't find the relevant TCP/IP settings to change the DNS.

I am using a BT Homehub 3 (type A) with software version: `4.7.5.1.83.8.94.1.37`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I change the DNS adresses on a BT Homehub 3?

Unfortunately you can't. BT have locked down DNS on their Homehub devices.

---

> BT lock the DNS server settings in firmware to prevent programs from changing the settings, and directing people to rogue DNS servers.

...

> There were vunerabilities with the early home hubs which allowed scripts to change the DNS settings.
>
> BT also like to make life easier for the helpdesk, and stopping alterations to the home hub reduces the likelihood of problems.
>
> There is a list of routers which can be used on ADSL and Infinity here.
>
> [Replacements for BT home hub 3](http://forumhelp.dyndns.org/speed/hh3replace.html) - this link is only accessible from a BT network ("Sorry, you can only access this site from a BT broadband connection.")

Source [Changing default DNS Server](https://community.bt.com/t5/Other-Broadband-Discussions/Changing-default-DNS-Server/td-p/191215/page/3)

---

> Most routers should let you alter the default DNS server addresses through their configuration page. This will affect every device that uses it to connect to the internet, making it the easiest way to change DNS servers if you have more than one internet-enabled device in the home. **Unfortunately for BT Broadband customers, this isn't possible on a BT Home Hub**.

Source [How to fix BT DNS issues using Google DNS](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/networks/1400420/how-to-fix-bt-dns-issues-using-google-dns)

---

#### Further reading

- [BT Home Hub - Information and Advice](http://www.filesaveas.com/bthomehub.html)
- [BT Home Hub, router and modem user guides](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/hub/c/1243,1245/?s_intcid=userguideshub_popular_routers#h=ImNhdD0xMjQzXzEyNDVfMTI1N3xjb2w9MyI.)

Comment: Does this apply for all HomeHubs, or just the HomeHub 3?

Comment: As far as I know it is all BT HomeHubs.

Comment: Most routers should let you alter the default DNS server addresses but if your aim is to use the OpenDNS site filtering service then you also need to ask your router to block requests to other DNS servers or your filtering can be bypassed.